# Adding fields dynamically inside an element which is also added dynamically Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a set of fields which can be duplicated. Now within those fields there are also particular fields which are duplicated.

This is an example of my markup

```
<div class="item_1">
<button type="button" class="fluid-inline btn btn-primary add_items">Add fields</button>
<hr />
 <div class="col-sm-4 m-b-10px">
   <label><h5>OCCUPATION: </h5></label>
   <input name=b_occ[] type="text" class="form-control" required=required>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 m-b-10px">
    <label><h5>WORK ADDRESS: </h5></label>
    <input name=b_work_add[] type="text" class="form-control" required=required>
  </div>
<div class="item_victim_relation">
   <div class="col-sm-4 m-b-10px">
     <label><h5>VICTIM: </h5></label>
     <select class="form-control" name="victim_name[]" required=required>
       <option value="victim_id"><h5>Victim</h5></option>
     </select>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-4 m-b-10px">
     <label><h5>RELATION TO VICTIM: </h5></label>
     <input name=b_relation[] type="text" class="form-control" required=required>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-4 m-b-10px">
     <h5 class="text-info">(IF SUSPECT HAS RELATION TO MULTIPLE VICTIMS) </h5>
     <button type="button" class="dashed-button add_victim_b">Add</button>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
var removeButtonV = "<button type=button class='dashed-button remove_item_v'>Remove</button>";
var removeButton = "<button type=button class='btn btn-primary m-b-10px remove_items'>Remove</button>";

$('.add_victim_b').click(function() {   
    $('div.item_victim_relation:last').
    after($('div.item_victim_relation:first').clone());  
    $('.add_victim_b:last').remove();   
    $('.text-info:last').text("(REMOVE THESE FIELDS)");   
    $(removeButtonV).insertAfter(('.text-info:last'));
});

$(document).on('click', '.remove_item_v', function(){
  $(this).closest('div.item_victim_relation').remove();
});


$('.add_items').click(function() {      
  $('div.item_1:last').after($('div.item_1:first').clone());       
  $('div.item_1:last').append(removeButton);
  $('hr.item_b_separator:last').removeClass('hidden');
});

$(document).on('click', '.remove_items', function(){
  $(this).closest('div.item_1').remove();
});
```

This piece of code duplicates victim and relation to victim fields. It works fine when item_1 is not yet duplicated, but when it is, those two fields are appended on the last instance of the fields inside the last instance of item_1 too. What I want to happen is for these two fields to be appended after their last instances on the item_1 where they belong.

I think my way of traversal is wrong. I've tried several methods but I can't seem to get it work.

Here is a demonstration of the problem:
[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/zwLxo3jj/4/)

Here is a [sample](https://jsfiddle.net/pk5887s4/) of what I want (each has their own class names and item_1 cannot be duplicated but it would not work if item_1 would be cloned)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it by changing my traversal methods and just assigning the fields to be added in a variable.
I have changed the handler of add_victim_b to this

```
    var victimFields = '<div class="item_victim_relation"><div class="col-sm-4 m-b-10px"><label><h5>VICTIM: </h5></label><select class="form-control" name="victim_name[]" required=required><option value="victim_id"><h5>Victim</h5></option></select></div><div class="col-sm-4 m-b-10px"><label><h5>RELATION TO VICTIM: </h5></label><input name=b_relation[] type="text" class="form-control" required=required></div><div class="col-sm-4 m-b-10px"><h5 class="text-info">(REMOVE FIELDS) </h5><button type="button" class="dashed-button remove_victim_b"><i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden=true></i></button></div><div class="clearfix"></div></div>';

    $(document).on('click', '.add_victim_b', function(){    
        var item_b_index = $(this).closest('.item_b').index('.item_b');  
        $(victimFields).insertAfter($('div.item_b').eq(item_b_index).find('.item_victim_relation:last'));
    });
```

It now works perfectly as I wanted it. You may view it here:
[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/zwLxo3jj/6/)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is only aware of the elements in the page at the time it runs, so new elements added to the DOM dynamically are unrecognized by jQuery. To combat the problem use event delegation, bubbling events from newly added items up to a point in the DOM which was there when jQuery ran on page load. Many people use document as the place to catch the bubbled event, but it isn't necessary to go all the way up the DOM tree. Ideally you should delegate to the nearest parent existing at the time of page load.

```
$(document).on('click', 'button.ok', function(e){...
```

Using the .on() function should solve your issue.

Comment: Hi! I already did this but it does not seem to solve the problem.